# I want to Aspect-Fill Image Slider in fixed sized div element

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, slider

I have several images with different sizes, and I am going to make image slider using these images.

I refer to [this document](http://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider).

But in this library, images are aspect fit in div element.

How to make image slider in which images are aspect-filled using various sizes images?

Answer (score 1):

The slideshow you linked to is set to display in aspect-fit mode. It's hard to tell this is happening but the images are filling the vertical and/or horizontal space depending on their aspect ratio.

The JSSOR slideshow has an option to define how the images are fit, and the example you linked to is set to 'Contain & Actual for Small Image'. This would mean it uses `aspect-fit` unless the image is too small to fill the height and/or width and it will center the image on the slide.

You can change how the images are fit by clicking the '[Edit This Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider/=edit)' link, then clicking 'Layout' and changing the Fill Mode on the right side. By default it appears to be set to `aspect-fit`, or 'Contain & Actual for Small Image'. If you want the images to fill both the height and width, which would require some images to be zoomed in on, you can select `cover`. This will case each image to fill the entire slide, by zooming and cropping parts of the image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I have to displayed images users uploaded dynamically.
So I can't edit each images one by one.

Comment: @Star_Man, this option is for all images, you don't need to edit any image.

Comment: I have to make aspect-filled image slider. But your answer made aspect-fited image slider only. All images must be fully filled in fixed div element without padding.

Comment: Did you try the other options and Preview the changes?

Comment: And this slider has static data about the sliding images. But I have to display any images users uploaded, so I can't contain any data of images.

Comment: The JSSOR slider might not be the best solution in your specific case.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I want the other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One day, I had developed similar code in such a case.
I know my code is not a wonderful way, but it runs many javascript codes, so it can make a performance problem.
This is my trial code. I want to help you a little either.

**html**

```
<div class="swiper-container thumbnails-preview" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1"
    data-speed="500" data-center="0" data-slides-per-view="1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide active" data-val="0">
             <div class="img_content">
                   <img class="img-responsive"  src="img_url"alt="">
                   <img class="img-responsive"  src="img_url"alt="">
                   ...
             </div>
        </div>
         <div class="pagination pagination-hidden poin-style-1"></div>
              <div class="arr-t-3">
                    <div class="swiper-arrow-left sw-arrow"><span class="fa fa-angle-left" style="left: 10px"></span></div>
                     <div class="swiper-arrow-right sw-arrow"><span class="fa fa-angle-right" style="right: 10px"></span>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(".img_content").each(function () {

        var parentWidth = $(this).width();
        var parentHeight = parentWidth * 0.7;

        $(this).css("height", parentHeight);
        $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");

        var target = $(this).children('img');
        var width = target.width();
        var height = target.height();

        var ratioXY = 0.5;

        var imgW = $(this).children('img').width();
        var imgH = $(this).children('img').height();


        //block size
        var block_width = $(this).closest(".swiper-container").width();
        var block_height = block_width * ratioXY;

        //image ratio
        var ratio = imgH / imgW;

        //image block size
        $(this).css("width", block_width);
        $(this).css("height", block_height);
        $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");

        if (ratio > ratioXY) {
            $(this).children('img').css("width", "100%");
            var gap = (imgH * block_width / imgW - block_height) / 2;
            $(this).children('img').css("margin-top", -gap);
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('img').css("height", "100%");
            $(this).children('img').css("max-width", 100 / ratio + "%");
            var gap = (imgW * block_height / imgH - block_width) / 2;
            $(this).children('img').css("margin-left", -gap);
        }
    });
```

As a matter of fact, I used **[idangerous swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/)** in my code.
However, it is okay to use another one, but I think how to use is almost same this.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is running well, But anything else? When I have to display a lot of images at once, it can occur javascript performance error in using your way.

Comment: I am glad my code is running well. I know about that problem. I want to learn another way, too.